# Can't Get Concrete Type From Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

I am registering an interface (`IFoo`) with the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` service as follows:

```
servicesBuilder.AddSingleton<IFooRepository, FooInMemoryRepository>();
```

Almost exclusively I am agnostic on the concrete type when I resolve the dependency as such:

```
services.GetRequiredService<IFooRepository>()
```

In which case everything works fine. However in rare instances I need the concrete implementation (`FooInMemoryRepository`) so I want to resolve that directly. I tried calling that

```
services.GetRequiredService<FooInMemoryRepository>()
```

However this throws an exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'UserQuery+FooInMemoryRepository' has been registered.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at UserQuery.Main() in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\LINQPad5\_ntmafjyh\query_eecehy.cs:line 37
```

Sample code (LINQPad):

```
void Main()
{
    var servicesBuilder = new ServiceCollection();
    servicesBuilder.AddSingleton<IFooRepository, FooInMemoryRepository>();
    servicesBuilder.AddSingleton<IFooRepository, FooOtherRepository>();
    var services = servicesBuilder.BuildServiceProvider();
    try
    {
        var foos = services.GetServices<IFooRepository>();
        foreach(var foo in foos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(foo.SomeMethod());
        }
        var ifoo = services.GetRequiredService<IFooRepository>();
        Console.WriteLine(ifoo.SomeMethod());
        var inMemoryRepo = services.GetRequiredService<FooInMemoryRepository>();
        Console.WriteLine(inMemoryRepo.SomeMethod());
    }
    catch(InvalidOperationException ioex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ioex.ToString());
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public interface IFooRepository
{
    string SomeMethod();
}

public class FooInMemoryRepository : IFooRepository
{
    public string SomeMethod() => "InMemory Foo";
}

public class FooOtherRepository : IFooRepository
{
    public string SomeMethod() => "Other Foo";
}
```

Output:

```
InMemory Foo
Other Foo
Other Foo
System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'UserQuery+FooInMemoryRepository' has been registered.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at UserQuery.Main() in C:\Users\TheGreatCO\AppData\Local\Temp\LINQPad5\_ntmafjyh\query_jcpvdk.cs:line 45
```

If I get *all* of the `IFooRepository` instances registered, I do get both. If I ask for just `IFooRepository` I get the *last* concrete implementation registered. If I ask for a specific concrete implementation, I get an `InvalidOperationException`.

Is it possible to resolve the concrete type from the dependency injector here or must I always resolve all of them, find which one I want and cast it to the concrete type?

Comment: You need to register your concrete implementation too if you want to resolve it, which you didnt in your examples above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but you have to register it explicitly.

In addition to

```
servicesBuilder.AddSingleton<IFooRepository, FooInMemoryRepository>();
servicesBuilder.AddSingleton<IFooRepository, FooOtherRepository>();
```

you also need

```
servicesBuilder.AddSingleton<FooInMemoryRepository>();
servicesBuilder.AddSingleton<FooOtherRepository>();
```

Comment: So if you have to register the implementation as well as the interface why does the `AddSingleton<TInterface, TImplementation>` method exist? Am I missing the point of it?

Comment: This registration is to register an interface with a concrete type, so you can resolve `TInterface`. If you want to resolve the concrete Class you need to register it bothwise `servicesBuilder.AddSingleton<FooInMemoryRepository, FooInMemoryRepository>();` which is the short-hand version of ``servicesBuilder.AddSingleton<FooInMemoryRepository>();`. The first type parameter always defines the requested type and the 2nd type parameter is for the concrete type

Comment: Other IoC containers main treat it differently, this is about Microsofts built-in DI/IoC. Others offer convinience features such as ".AsInterfaces()" which registers all interfaces of a concrete type or will allow resolving unregistered object when resolving a concrete type. Its not the case for MS DI which is meat to be simple to get started and easy to replace with 3rd party solutions

Comment: Please be _very_ aware that having the two `AddSingleton` calls (as shown in the asnwer) for the same implementation will result into _two instances_, _not one_!! In other words, the lifestyle of `FooInMemoryRepository` becomes _torn_. This might not be a problem in all cases, but it sometimes matters a lot. So be very careful.